# AngularJS ng-options exception

Tags: angularjs, select

I have options for my select and I will show all options exept the one of the container. Is there any possibility to do that:

```
<div ng-repeat="userScheduleManagementWeeksContainer in vm.userScheduleManagementWeeksContainer track by $index">               
            <select ng-options="c as c.calendarWeek for c in vm.userScheduleManagementWeeksContainer **except c == userScheduleManagementWeeksContainer.calendarWeek**">
                <option value="" />
            </select>
```

**[EDIT]**

DIV- Container1:
41
42
43

DIV- Container1:
40
42
43

DIV- Container1:
40
41
43

...

Comment: Why don't you remove it from your array, if you don't want it to be displayed ?

Comment: because it is hard to do, the options are the same for all my div- container except the option of the container itselve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use ng-if like as follows

```
<div ng-repeat="userScheduleManagementWeeksContainer in vm.userScheduleManagementWeeksContainer track by $index">               
  <select>
    <option value="" />
    <option ng-repeat="c in vm.userScheduleManagementWeeksContainer" ng-if="c.calendarWeek != userScheduleManagementWeeksContainer.calendarWeek" value="{{c.calendarWeek}}">{{c.calendarWeek}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Another option is to use filters. This will allow you to put the object in the ng-model

```
<div ng-repeat="userScheduleManagementWeeksContainer in vm.userScheduleManagementWeeksContainer track by $index">               
  <select ng-options="c as c.calendarWeek for c in vm.userScheduleManagementWeeksContainer | filter : { calendarWeek : '!' + userScheduleManagementWeeksContainer.calendarWeek }">
    <option value="" />
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, the suggestion does work almost, I have one more question. at select tag I have a ng-model - in the model the whole object c should be stored, not only the calendar week. Is there a way to do this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I updated my answer to include a second option. Hope that worked for you as you wanted.